# How do I write awk '{print $1+$2+$3} file1 > file2 for n columns instead of 3?

Tags: text-processing, awk

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum[i]+=$i} END{for (i in sum) print sum[i]}' file1 > file2
```

This helps sum all record-wise but a similar scheme wouldn't help do a column-wise sum (maybe). How to generalize column-wise addition to n columns?

```
cat file1
23 46 45
45 57 58
56 78 74

cat file2
114
160
208
```

Comment: @user1271772 Committed to Materials Modeling SE. Thanks for the suggestion. It received 100 % commitment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to compute the sum of the fields for each record, so it's just:

```
awk '{sum = 0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) sum += $i; print sum}' < file1 > file2
```

The curly braces begin an *action* statement that is executed on every line of the input; there is no preceding *condition* that would limit its execution to lines that satisfy such a *condition*.

On each line:

1. Initialize a `sum` variable to zero.
2. Loop through the fields, starting at field #1 and ending at the last field (the special variable `NF`), and increment `sum` by the value of that field (`$i`).
3. Print the value of the `sum` variable.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't complete. The command keeps running with no change on the terminal.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania, you need to feed input to it, like by adding `< file1` if that input is in the `file1` file.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. But I don't understand it, can you please explain it to me.

Comment: @HitanshuSachania if you don't understand that, then how were you able to write the version from your answer, which is more complicated? (Notice however that the `(for i in sum)` is **not** guaranteed to iterate though the keys in any specific order (and it the real `nawk` the order for the 1..100 keys will be something like 59,22,2,23,3,...,21,1).

Comment: @mosvy For no particular reason, I got confused between the use of an array to sum the vales VS a single variable. It's clear now.  I'll avoid "for i in something", though why is it that it doesn't follow a specific order?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania because awk arrays are usually implemented using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and each implementation may use its own hash function, and may iterate through the keys in the order in which they're stored in the table + linked lists structure. Even with `mawk` (the default `awk` in debian) the following will print 21 first: `awk 'BEGIN{a[1]=a[21]=1;for(i in a) print i}'`

Comment: @mosvy, though GNU `awk` has options to scan arrays in the numerical order of its keys (`PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"`; see `info gawk 'array scanning'`).

Answer (score 1):

This will be a little slower than awk, but it's very concise:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum0 -lane 'print sum0(@F)' file1
```

It uses the [`sum0`](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#sum0) function of the core List::Util module.

Comment: `perl -lane 'my $s; $s += $_ for @F; print $s' < file1`